# java httpserver handling POST requests and read the html form information

Tags: java, http, post, httpserver

I am trying to write a simple HTTP server in java that can handle & read POST requests which is coming from html form

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
server.setExecutor(null); 
server.start();
}
 static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {

   @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
     system.out.println("Serving the request");

     if (he.getRequestMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
  try {
     Headers requestHeaders = he.getRequestHeaders();
     Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> entries = requestHeaders.entrySet();

     int contentLength = Integer.parseInt(requestHeaders.getFirst("Content-length"));
     System.out.println(""+requestHeaders.getFirst("Content-length"));

     InputStream is = he.getRequestBody();

     byte[] data = new byte[contentLength];
     int length = is.read(data);

     Headers responseHeaders = he.getResponseHeaders();

     he.sendResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, contentLength);

     OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody();

     os.write(data);
     he.close();

     } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
     }
     }

    }
    }
    }
```

above code read the post data from html form and gives output on browsers window 
but i want to display the form information in java console so how can i do that?  so please help me.

Comment: When you post code it should work. Java is case sensitive so system.out is something different then System.out. I corrected and formatted your code.

Comment: my edit got rejected, maybe because I accidentally added one line. Maybe you can fix it by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I did not test it because I have no form ready to send a POST message or don't know how I can create a HTTP POST message from scratch.

You can print the data you already read to the console by using the String class:

```
System.out.print(new String(data));
```